# Using PyQt and the QTableWidget to set in image in the horizontalHeaderItem

Tags: qt, pyqt, qtablewidget, qtablewidgetitem

I tried sub-classing the QTableWidgetItem and then set my horizontalHeaderItem with that new sub-classed class. for instance:

```
class ImageWidget(QtGui.QTableWidgetItem):

def __init__(self, imagePath, parent):
    super(ImageWidget, self).__init__(parent)
    self.picture = QtGui.QPixmap(imagePath)

def paintEvent(self, event):
    painter = QtGui.QPainter(self)
    painter.drawPixmap(0, 0, self.picture)

class showTable(QtGui.QDialog):

def __init__(self, parent=None):
    tableWidget = QtGui.QTableWidget(10, 2)
    imagePath = "C:/Documents and Settings/pwr37669/workspace/Pro_GUI_Py/images/led_green.gif"
    item = ImageWidget(imagePath, QtGui.QTableWidgetItem())
    tableWidget.setHorizontalHeaderItem(0, item)

    tableWidget.show()
```

I know that code won't work, but, I'm trying to get something like that to work.

I also need to change the results of clicking on a cell or the header.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks,
Stephen

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following seems to do the trick:

```
class ImgWidget1(QtGui.QLabel):

    def __init__(self,imagePath, parent=None):
        super(ImgWidget1, self).__init__(parent)

        pic = QtGui.QPixmap(imagePath)
        self.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.setPixmap(pic)
```

And then when I wanted to add an image I did this:

```
self.tableWidget.setCellWidget(rows, cells, ui_polling.ImgWidget1(imagePath))
```

Hope this helps someone out there.

Answer (score 1):

Pls, check if an example below would work for you:

```
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore

class MainForm(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MainForm, self).__init__(parent)

        tableWidget = QtGui.QTableWidget()
        tableWidget.setRowCount(3)
        tableWidget.setColumnCount(2)

        for column in range(0, 2):
            for row in range(0, 3):
                print row, column
                item = QtGui.QTableWidgetItem("new item")
                tableWidget.setItem(row, column, item)

        headerItem = QtGui.QTableWidgetItem("Header Test")
        headerItem.setIcon(QtGui.QIcon(QtGui.QPixmap("your_image.png")))
        headerItem.setTextAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignVCenter);

        tableWidget.setHorizontalHeaderItem(0, headerItem)

        tableWidget.itemClicked.connect(self.on_tableWidget_itemClicked)
        tableWidget.connect(tableWidget.horizontalHeader(), QtCore.SIGNAL('sectionClicked(int)'), self.on_headersection_clicked)

        self.setCentralWidget(tableWidget)

    def on_tableWidget_itemClicked(self, item):
        print "item clicked " + item.text()

    def on_headersection_clicked(self, item):
        print "header section clicked " + str(item) 

def main():
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    form = MainForm()
    form.show()
    app.exec_()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

hope this helps, regards

Comment: I've tried this, but, unfortunately, all I get is an icon sized image next to the header text.  I'm trying to replace the header text with an image, inevitably increasing the height of the header.  My other option is to try to rotate the text 90 degrees.